# service worker canceling out REST urls

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app

just started working with reactjs recently, month or two..not a pro but can find my way around.. I am using create ract app (quickie ,that ships with service-worker) and my setup is such that I am deploying react app in the root of my java REST application, so all my service rest calls are in relative format, e.g /rest/myservice/123 etc.. and they work just fine..

but recently I started getting strange errors, and rest calls stopped working..
if I execute RET URL from browser .... nothing happens index loads... when I test with postman REST works just fine it also  works in safari or if url is localhost... ...so after hours of frustration i discovered that  service worker doing its .... caching . my rest calls are getting intercepted and they never make it to server... and there is nowhere that it mentions about how to overcome it, neither in service worker docs nor in create-react-app docs ...nothing is mentioned about this use case...... this is so pathetic...
I figured it out after numerous trail and errors... but it did not stop there..
I went ahead and deleted the service-worker registration entry from index.js also deleted service-worker file and rebuild the app. well service-worker.js file is still there... it showed up in build folder after I rebuild the project..... what is it with create-react-app did they got paid by google to include service-worker? or what is going on? why can not I remove  it? and how do I prevent it from canceling my rest url calls?
when I type : https://xxxx.io/x/referal/refCode/3429878 it just loads application...

what else am I missing?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2398   try looking at your build... you have an SW in there that u need to know about

Comment: I need to eject in that case, which I am trying to avoid.. question is why does it work this way out of the box, makes no sense at all

Answer (score 1):

got the answer over @Redit needed to unregister worker...

details @:

https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/8hovvb/removal_of_serviceworker_from_reactjs_app/